# Explode array's data and make new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a,b,c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => d,e,f
        )
)
```

I want the final array to be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => c
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => d
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => e
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => f
        )
)
```

This is what I did:

```
<?php
    $array = array(array(1,"a,b,c"),array(5,"d,e,f"));
    $temp=array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array as $arr){
        $rows = explode(",",$arr[1]);
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $temp[$count] = $arr;
            $temp[$count][1] = $row;
            $count++;
        }
    }
    print_r($temp);
?>
```

This totally works but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. This can be very slow when I have huge data.

Comment: Using loops will generally be the fastest way. Often slowness is caused by inefficient loops, but that doesn't appear to be the case here. Your dataset would have to be genuinely MASSIVE for this to have a significant impact on the execution time of your script.

Comment: are you saying this is the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Loops will generally always be the fastest way. Using some callback function like `array_map` (not that this will work here) will be slower.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way...

```
<?php

$array = array(array(1,"a,b,c"),array(5,"d,e,f"));
$temp=array();
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $arr){
    $rows = explode(",",$arr[1]);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $temp[$count][] = $arr[0];
        $temp[$count][] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
}

/*print "<pre>";
  print_r($temp);
  print "<pre>";*/

?>
```

Comment: The problem is you copied the code from question itself, had to down vote you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional approach:

```
$result = array_merge(...array_map(function(array $a) {
    return array_map(function($x) use ($a) {
        return [$a[0], $x];
    }, explode(",", $a[1]));
}, $array));
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/6CW6t).

Or simply with two loops:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach (explode(",", $a[1]) as $x) {
        $result[] = [$a[0], $x];
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/IH32o).

Timing these reveals that a simple loop construct is ~8 times faster.

- functional: `4.06s user 0.08s system 99% cpu 4.160 total`
- loop: `0.53s user 0.05s system 102% cpu 0.561 total`

Comment: Is it faster than what we have?

Comment: @Prakash: Nope, actually a lot slower than by simply looping the array. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need other way around,

```
$array = array(array(1, "a,b,c"), array(5, "d,e,f"));
$temp  = [];
array_walk($array, function ($item, $key) use (&$temp) {
    $second = explode(',', $item[1]);
    foreach ($second as $v) {
        $temp[] = [$item[0], $v];
    }
});
print_r($temp);
```

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b497c8516a3f24d1e3ff7971372c625260bb9d4).